# Bigger version of &bull;

Tags: html, special-characters, html-entities

Is there a bigger version of `&bull;`?

• Right now it is this big

- I want it this big without using font sizes or `<li>`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You could put it in a `<span>` with a bigger font but the same `line-height`.

You can also try BLACK CIRCLE `&#x25cf;` ●.
I don't know how many platforms that will work on, though.

Comment: The black circle is quite big. A bullet that's sometimes in between these two is `&#x2219;` aka `&#8729;`.

Comment: @franzo the `&#x2219;` and `&#8729;` renders as this: ∙
I guess it depends on your font.

Comment: This works perfectly if you're doing a table and want a marker to indicate a certain cell.

Answer (score 7):

Easy my friend! Check this:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul li::before {
    content: "● ";
    color: #2C92C5;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the `font-size` in CSS higher:

```css
.bullelements{
  font-size:2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...<span class="bullelements">&bull;</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now you can set the `font-size` to your size.

Comment: If you are to use rem as your font-size, it's also good you know how it works, it is dependent on html font-size

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to make the element bold

```
<span class="bull-element">&bull;</span> item <br />
<span class="bull-element">&bull;</span> item

<style>
    .bull-element {
        font-weight: 900;
    }
</style>
```